# Trouble updating data using form Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a form with controller name as Spec. The view file corresponding to the controller is as follows

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :spec do |form| %>
<fieldset>
<legend><%= @title %></legend>

<%= text_field_for form, "first_name" %>
<%= text_field_for form, "last_name" %>
<div class="form_row">
<label for="gender">Gender: </label>

<%= radio_button :spec, :gender, "Male" %> Male
<%= radio_button :spec, :gender, "Female" %> Female
<%= radio_button :spec, :gender, "Other" %> Other
 </div>
<br />
<div class="form_row">
<label for="birthdate">Birthdate:</label>
<%= date_select :spec, :birthdate,
            :start_year => Spec::START_YEAR,
            :end_year => Time.now.year,
            :include_blank => true,
            :order => [:month,:day,:year] %>
</div>
<%= text_field_for form, "occupation" %>
<%= text_field_for form, "city" %>
<%= text_field_for form, "state" %>
<%= text_field_for form, "zip_code", Spec::ZIP_CODE_LENGTH %>

<%= submit_tag "Update", :class => "submit" %>
</fieldset>
```

The controller file is

spec_controller.rb

```
class SpecController < ApplicationController
before_filter :protect
def index
unless session[:user_id]
    flash[:notice]="Please login first"
    redirect_to :controller => "sessions", :action => "new"
else
redirect_to :controller => "users", :action => "index"
end  
end

  def edit
unless session[:user_id]
    flash[:notice]="Please login first"
    redirect_to :controller => "sessions", :action => "new"
else    

@title = "Update"
@user= User.find(session[:user_id])
@user.spec ||= Spec.new
if param_posted?(:spec)
   if @user.spec.update_attributes(params[:spec])
    flash[:success]="Update Successful!"
    redirect_to :controller => "users", :action => "index"
   end
  end
end
 end
end
```

My routes.rb has

```
get "spec/index"
get "spec/edit"
```

and also
    resource :spec

However, when I try to click update button from edit.html.erb the submitted form returns

No route matches [POST] "/spec/edit" error

User logs:

```
Started POST "/spec/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-08 17:58:51 -0400
Processing by SpecController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MUcDsRrrQtJS/iswvhkH/Ujm2d3jIip/d1rJOFjC+fM=", "spec"=>{"first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"Check", "gender"=>"Male", "birthdate(2i)"=>"1", "birthdate(3i)"=>"1", "birthdate(1i)"=>"1991", "occupation"=>"Student", "city"=>"Cosmos", "state"=>"Earth", "zip_code"=>"12345"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Spec Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `specs`.* FROM `specs` WHERE `specs`.`user_id` = 1 ORDER BY `specs`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Spec: first_name, last_name, gender, birthdate(2i), birthdate(3i), birthdate(1i), occupation, city, state, zip_code
app/controllers/spec_controller.rb:22:in `edit'
  (0.2ms)  COMMIT
```

can anybody help with some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form, its generating a **POST** request as `/spec/edit`.

You have defined a **GET** request in your routes and not POST. Hence, the error.
Change your route to **post** and your current code would work.

**UPDATE**

As per the `WARNING` in server log:

> WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Spec: first_name,
>   last_name, gender, birthdate(2i), birthdate(3i), birthdate(1i),
>   occupation, city, state, zip_code
>   app/controllers/spec_controller.rb:22:in `edit'

You need to white-list the attributes in `Spec` model using `attr_accessible`.

For example:

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :gender,.....,etc
```

Comment: Ah! I figured out lately! that was dumb. Thanks though!

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with the above code? Because even if the params are getting submitted their values are not getting updated in the database. Instead they remain null.

Comment: Can you share the server log generated upon submission of this form? Add it in the question.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks as always! :D Hope i get much better with ruby on rails soon!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
get "spec/edit"
```

to

```
post "spec/edit"
```